# Javascript copy & symbol from div to input malfunction

Tags: javascript, php, html

I cannot find an answer to this question...

The problem. Javascript copying text from DIV to input (textbox), fails to copy `&` as `&`, and copies it as `&amp;`. See code plus example.

I have the following code (on different pages, just to simplify I put all here):

INPUT where I want the text copied.

```
<input name="artist" id="txtArtist" type="text" placeholder="Introduce the artist" />
```

DIV where the text is copied from. This data is populated from a SQL database.

```
<div id="art0"><div onclick="copyText(0)">Mumford & Sons</div></div>'
```

The function that fails...

```
function copyText(rowID){
    var content = document.getElementById('art'+rowID).innerHTML.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "\n");
    document.getElementById("txtArtist").value = document.getElementById('art'+rowID).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("txtArtist").value = content;
}
```

EXPECTED result inside textbox: `Mumford & Sons`

ACTUAL result inside textbox: `Mumford &amp; Sons`

Any help please?

Thank you all!!

Comment: Just copy `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Did you view source to see that "Mumford & Sons" is in fact "Mumford & Sons" instead of "Mumford &amp; Sons" because `&` is escaped in many cases by sanitize procedures.

Comment: @Victory -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lvm8s/

Comment: @adeneo yeah that might be tricky for people trying to learn because both escaped/not-escaped tend to render the same http://jsfiddle.net/Lvm8s/1/

Comment: @Victory Hmmm, I checked source code and in fact you are right! It is Mumford &amp; Sons in the source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`:

```
var content = document.getElementById('art'+rowID).textContent;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Tr5T/1/

Note that `.textContent` is not supported by IE 8 and lower, so if you are so unfortunate, test for and use `.innerText` instead.

```
var prop = 'textContent' in document.body ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
    content = document.getElementById('art'+rowID)[prop];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Tr5T/2/

Comment: use `.textContent` instead for FF.

Comment: take care: `.textContent` is >I9 compatible... for <I8 use `.innerText`

Comment: I edit your fiddle with simple test to change `.textContent` if is `undefined`.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Tr5T/3/